# Auto re-size font of textBox to show all text in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, autoresize

There is a textBox on a form that we can write some characters inside and then print the form. My problem is that sometimes number of characters are more than textBox length so it can't show all text to print. So I need to auto re_size the font of textBox.
What is your simplest method to do this?

My problem:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791830/autoscale-font-in-a-textbox-control-so-that-its-as-big-as-possible-and-still-fit

Comment: If user should type text there, and there's no limit to the amount of text the user can enter then reducing the font size is not the optimal solution. Fonts have limits too. Consider some other approach, like a tooltip or expandable window, that would show all the text in usual font size.