# C# Drawstring fit to image with wordwrap

Tags: c#, watermark

I need to add a text to an Image if my programm is not activated. This text should fill the whole image. It should also wrap and scale to fit the image as needed.

I found a lot of working solutions to add this text scaled to the image size. But in every case, it's only one line of text, and so won't wrap as I want it too.

How can I set the font size depending on the imagesize and use wordwrap?

EDIT:
It's a winforms application.

EDIT 2: What I tried to do:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.MasterPath + @"\***\***\***\" + file.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);

string text = "Some Text";
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
Font font = new Font("Arial", 120, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red));

Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
float sy = (float)b.Height / (float)1240; //I used 1240 and 1844 because on an image with
float sx = (float)b.Width / (float)1844; //this size the text had the right size
graphics.ScaleTransform(sx, sy);
graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, rec, stringFormat);

b.Save(this.MasterPath + @"\***\***\***\" + file.Name, img.RawFormat);
img.Dispose();
b.Dispose();
```

Comment: You failed to mention what application you're making? Win Forms, Web App, Mobile App, ...? And why don't you just create a default image that can be scaled to any size you need?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a winforms application.

Comment: I don't use a default image, because the relation between the width and height of the target image is different, so the text on the default image would be stretched or if I center the default image, won't cover the whole image

Comment: One more thing that needs clarification, you say that you want the text the fill the whole image. do you want the font size to scale to fit the space or do you want the text to break if it exceeds the width? Or do you want to generate starts "*" based on the space available and fill it that way?

You could just center the single line of text as you do now and fill the background with a single color or add a border to mimic the image's size.

Comment: Yes I want the font size to scale. Found a solution for this, no problem
Also I want the text to brake. Found a solution for this, no problem

Comment: The problem is to combine both.

Comment: There is more space if the text brakes, so the size can be bigger

Comment: Now I understand completely what you're trying to achieve. Could you perhaps share some code to see what exactly you have already? Makes it easier to work with. And is there any kind of consistency with the image sizes or shapes or are there infinite variations? (For example the images only exist in following proportions/ratios: "1:1" , "2:1", "4:3")

Comment: Added some code. Tried a lot of different stuff, this was the last try. The image size is unknown, could be everything

Answer (score 1):

It is a really rough concept to work out.

I think the easiest solution would be to replace the graphic on your form with the a RichTextBox control and just edit the layout so it looks transparent.

Then you could use the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/854773/4579864) (by @blak3r) to get the wanted result.

---

**EDIT:**
If you want an image from it you could use the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(richTextBox1.Width, richTextBox1.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToScreen(richTextBox1.Location), new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size);
bmp.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
g.Dispose();
bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: This would be a solution, if I'd like to display the image, but I need to save the image with the text on it and do a lot of other stuff, like generate thumbnails and show it on an asp.net page...

Comment: I've added how to do this in my answer.

Comment: But for therefore I have to display the image. But I'm processing hundreds of images and the user shouldn't see anything of it.

Comment: I thought that the whole point was to display it as you were creating a winform application. Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791830/autoscale-font-in-a-textbox-control-so-that-its-as-big-as-possible-and-still-fit/854773#854773) entire explanation carefully? Using the graphic rendering technique does not account for word wrapping so you'd have to write your own implementation for the line breaking if you wish to do this properly. Thats why RichTextBox is so usefull.

Comment: You could perhaps use this method until you get the perfect font size and then do the linebreaking yourself without ever having to display the image.