# Viewbox alternative using Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, viewbox

I'm getting used to WPF and it's sometimes very painful to come back to Winforms development. I'm looking for some kind of alternative to the WPF Viewbox for Winforms. Do you have any idea?

My major issue is that I need to update dynamically the size of the Font used in a Label control and/or a Picture control.

Answer (score 1):

There is none... Would it be possible to [host WPF controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) or are you stuck with .NET 2.0? If so, I'm afraid something that dynamically changes your text size will need to be used. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388937/determine-label-size-based-upon-amount-of-text-and-font-size-in-winforms-c) post out in this case.