# Is there a measurestring equivalent in Silverlight xaml?

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, xaml

What I am trying to accomplish:
Create a dynamic bubble that expands on height and width depending on the amount of text in the bubble.

What I researched so far:
In a SO [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388937/determine-label-size-based-upon-amount-of-text-and-font-size-in-winforms-c) they described utilizing the measurestring function to figure out the exact width or height so dynamic changes in the .cs to the width and height can be accomplished.

Is there something like this in Silverlight?  Is the only option I have is to utilize the myTxt.Text.length and then change the myGrid.height and myGrid.width to leave wasted space to accommodate all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `TextBlock` you will find the properties `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`. I think that is what you are looking for.